# Como faço para repetir uma string em Python?

Tags: python, string

A pergunta é simples: Como faço para repetir uma `string` em Python?

Estou acostumado com o PHP.

Quando quero repetir uma string em PHP, faço assim:

```
var $str = 'StackOverflow';
str_repeat($str, 5); 
// Imprime: StackOverflowStackOverflowStackOverflowStackOverflowStackOverflow
```

Tentei isso:

```
'StackOverflow'.repeat(5);
```

Porém é retornado um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'repeat'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta multiplicar a string desejada.

```
a = 'StackOverflow'
print (a * 5)
```

o retorno será:

```
'StackOverflowStackOverflowStackOverflowStackOverflowStackOverflow'
```

Comment: Nesse caso, o `*=5`  mudará o valor diretamente em `a`. Então, eu teria que simplesmente que fazer `a * 5` se eu quisesse que o valor repetisse, sem alterar a variável original?

Comment: `'StackOverflow' * 5` diretamente também serve.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, exato. Vou editar minha resposta pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Acho que postar essas variações na respostas pode enriquecer no conhecimento :), só uma dica

Answer (score 7):

Isto é suficiente para você?

```
str = 'StackOverflow'
print ((str[:13] + ' ') * 5)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/0Tjcyt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qhduileb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Multiply.py).

A [repetição ocorre com o operador de multiplicação](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Strings). Muitos criticam a sobrecarga do operador para uso com *strings*, mas se pensar bem, faz sentido.

É possível pegar um trecho da *string* usando o operador de [*slice*](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings), ou seja, ele pega uma parte da *string* que nada mais é, a grosso modo, que um *array* de caracteres.

Comment: Por que do `:13`?

Comment: Você pegar a parte que você deseja repetir.

Comment: o.O! Que legal! Para fazer isso no PHP eu teria que usar o `substr` e `str_replace` encadeados! O Python é mucho simples

Comment: Coloquei de um jeito que funciona no Python 3 também. O que eu gosto na linguagem é que ela tenta na maior parte do tempo realmente tornar os códigos menores, mais simples.